# LayoutInflater not displays the xml properly

Tags: android, android-studio, layout-inflater

I'm trying to use LayoutInflater for creating from xml layout some custom View.

MainActivity:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.t1);

        Widget w = new Widget(getApplicationContext());

        layout.addView(w.getView());
    }
```

Widget:

```
 private Context context;
    public Widget(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public View getView(){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.widget, null);
        ((Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button)).setText("button");
        ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView)).setText("text");

        return view;
    }
```

widget.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

But I got two problems:

1. Activity displays only button without TextView.
2. Button has black colour and white text, but in preview it has grey colour and black text.

How can I solve these problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have to change your res/values/styles.xml params.
With Android Studio 2.0 you can use the Theme Editor. Pretty nice if you don't need special buttons etc.

Or you can add custom colos for each view. For example add

```
android:textColor="@color/yourcolor1"
android:background="@color/yourcolor2"
```

to your text view. res/values/colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
 <color name="yourcolor1">#FFFFFF</color>
 <color name="yourcolor2">#CCCCCC</color>
</resources>
```

Change your button attributes too like this (just examples):

```
android:textColor="@android:color/black"
android:background"@android:color/darker_gray"
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem was due to colour. And where can I check default styles for views(styles which I see in preview when I open layout, e.g grey button with black text)?